# Inserting .js with <script> tag in php file (main.js/app.js) not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, templates, laravel-mix

Well, basically this is not really a big deal.

I am currently working on a tutorial, trying to play around with custom template tags and webpack. When I am trying to write some javascript in an external file(like main.js or app.js)it does not work, if I add it within a  tag in a .php file.

However, this is a issue which emerges from time to time and I have no clue why it does not work. My assumption is, that this has something to the with the file path.

The "magic" issue does not appear, if I rename my .php to a .html file.
I'd use this as an alternative, but my current project is in need to be written in a .php file! (To the code down below: my self created template also just useable in a .html file, but not .php)

### welcome.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>

<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">


    <div id="app">
        <notification></notification>#from the vue
    </div>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script> #path seems to be correct


</body>

</html>
```

---

### app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import Notification from './components/Notification.vue'

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    components:{Notification}
})
```

---

### Notification.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="notification">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello World"
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.notification {
  background: green;
}
</style>
```

There is no actual issue, but I am not able to use the written code in my external file nor am I able to use my predefined tags.

Thanks in advance boys!

Comment: What are you trying to add to your `app.js`? Also, have you run `webpack` to recompile your JS code (`npm run watch`)

Comment: Just simple styling lere here (https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/23) and yes I did run the php run production command, it's basically the same

Comment: Try `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`